# Update query only make the database table field empty

Tags: php, mysql, oop, sql-update

I have made an Update query with PHP OOP. Basically here is the `itemedit.php` page where users can update the database table fields:

```
    <form action='itemedit.php?i=$i' method='POST'>
                                    <td>$i</td>
                                    <td><input type='text' name='e' value='".$menuSet->$func()."'/></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type='submit' value='Edit'/>&nbsp; 
                                        <a title='Remove' href='itemdelete.php?i=$i'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </form>
```

If you wanna know about the theory behind this see my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651019/how-to-pass-name-of-an-input-through-get-request-in-php)...

And then here I have coded this for updating that custom field:

```
public function EditMenuItem($i,$e)
        {
            if(!empty($i))
            {
                $adm = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE menu_nav SET menu_link_$i = ?");
                $adm->bindParam(1, $e, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $adm->execute();
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: php/includes/errors/012.php");
                exit();
            }
        }
```

And here is the action of file of that form:

```
if (isset($_GET['i'])){
    $i = $_GET['i'];
    $e = $_POST['e'];
    $editItem = new Menus();

    if(isset($_POST['yes'])){
        $editItem->EditMenuItem($i,$e);
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=menus.php">';   
        exit; 
    }
    if(isset($_POST['no'])){
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=menus.php">';    
        exit; 
    }

    echo "
    <div class='content-wrapper'>
        <section class='content-header'>
            <h1>
                Editing Menu Item
                <small></small>
            </h1>
            <ol class='breadcrumb'>
                <li class='active'>itemedit.php</li>
            </ol>
        </section>
        <section class='content' style='text-align:center;'>
            <form action='' method='POST'>
                <h5><strong> 
                    Are you sure you want to change the selected item ?</br></br>
                </strong></h5>   
                <p> 
                    <button name='yes' type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Yes</button>
                    <button name='no' type='submit' class='btn'>No</button>
                </p> 
            </form> 
        </section>
    </div>
    ";
```

And it works fine but the problem is it ONLY make the table field in MySQL database empty and null for some reasons..

So if you know how to solve this, please let me know I really appreciate it ?

Comment: How/When are you calling this function `EditMenuItem`?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write that down, see the question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because on the 2nd iteration when users select yes or no, the form doesnt have values for the `$_POST['e']`.

Change this

```
<p>
<button name='yes' type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Yes</button>
<button name='no' type='submit' class='btn'>No</button>
</p>
```

to

```
<p>
<input type='hidden' name='e' value='<?php echo $e;?>'>
<button name='yes' type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Yes</button>
<button name='no' type='submit' class='btn'>No</button>
</p>
```